# Creating executable Python scripts for wider audiences

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable, cx-freeze

I have read several posts regarding creating .exe files from Python scripts using tools like cx_freeze or pyinstaller and read a few articles which basically admit to having the same issues as the posts do - namely, the .exe files are simply too large (sometimes in the hundreds of MB). I have tried this myself on a script and simply because libraries like Numpy and Pandas were packaged into it, the executable became massive.

This is a bit of real world scenario so I am taking a shot here at asking about this but is there no way to create solutions for teams who do NOT have coding experience? The only options I can think of are:

1. Require all users to have Python and the related libraries installed on their systems and train them in running the scripts.
2. Perhaps push the script to a cloud service and run the script from there (though this may be an issue when it needs to connect to inhouse databases and other source systems).
3. Accept the size of the .exe file and save it on shared drives and go for a lunch break every time you need to run it.

Comment: You could just require Python and [`pipx`](https://github.com/pypa/pipx) to be installed, and make your programs pipx compatible, and have your users use it to run them...

Comment: I have a solution for you... Write your applications in a compiled language.  It will dramatically decrease the size of the executable.